# Java comparator get all unmatched fields

Tags: java, comparator

I have a class for comparing all the property values of an object with another using reflection api. The problem i am facing is, Here i am getting the name of those getter method's of the objects whose values don't match, but I want the name's of properties whose values don't match.

How can i achieve this using the below code?

```
package myclass.util;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;

public class GenericComparator {
    private static final String NOT_EQUALS = "%s: [ %s ] != [ %s ]";
    private static final String REFLECT_ERROR = "%s: ERROR -> %s";

    public static List<String> compareGetters(Object base, Object compareTo, List<String> ignoreFields) {
        List<String> notEquals = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Method method : getGetters(base.getClass(), ignoreFields)) {
            try {
                Method compareMethod = compareTo.getClass().getMethod(method.getName());
                Object baseResult = method.invoke(base);
                Object compareResult = compareMethod.invoke(compareTo);
                if (!new EqualsBuilder().append(baseResult, compareResult).isEquals()) {
                    notEquals.add(String.format(NOT_EQUALS, method.getName(), baseResult, compareResult));
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                notEquals.add(String.format(REFLECT_ERROR, method.getName(), e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
        return notEquals;
    }

    public static List<Method> getGetters(Class clazz, List<String> ignoreFields) {
        if (ignoreFields == null) {
            ignoreFields = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        ignoreFields.add("class");
        List<Method> getters = new ArrayList<Method>();

        // get getters
        Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (isGetter(method) && !listContainsString(ignoreFields, method.getName())) {
                getters.add(method);
            }
        }
        return getters;
    }

    private static boolean listContainsString(List<String> list, String string) {
        boolean contains = false;
        for (String item : list) {
            if (string.toUpperCase().contains(item.toUpperCase())) {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return contains;
    }

    /**
     * @param method
     * @return true or false if the method is a getter
     */
    public static boolean isGetter(Method method) {
        if (!method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (method.getParameterTypes().length != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (void.class.equals(method.getReturnType())) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your getters is always which one expected :
`getPropOne()` where `propOne` is the name of a field, you can deduce the name of the field referenced by the getter :

```
String getterName = ...;
String firstLetter = getterName.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase();
String fieldName = firstLetter + getterName.subString(4);
```

Otherwise and/or if you want to ensure that the supposed name refers actually to a field of the class, use reflection "again" to find the fields associated to the getters by relying on the getter naming convention.
If a getter is found and that no field associated is found, you should probably log a warning or a similar thing.

`Class.getDeclaredFields()` would be useful to achieve this task.
Note that even if you know which name the field should have, the `Class.getField(String)` method should not be used as fields are generally private and the second one returns only `public` fields.